# Is there a way to access, read and modify System Volume Information?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus-removal

I have an issue with a virus that is located in System Volume Information. However, **I can't even see the folder in order to give myself ownership / permissions, even though I do have the "Show hidden files and folders" option enabled**. I also tried to enter it using WinRar, modifying the registries, using Command Prompt or Safe Mode, but it didn't work.
***So, is there any way to grant myself the permission to enter it?***

*Note: I used an old antivirus program (AVG2013) but it didn't work at all, and I can't get a newer one because installing it requires an internet connection. And I don't want to connect for multiple reasons. And I'm pretty sure that it still won't get removed because of the lack of permissions.*

Edit: I'm not talking about usual virus removal here. I'm talking about virus removal in a super protected folder.

Comment: 1. From where do you know it's located there? 2. Even if you'd have access,  what could you do? System volume information is not something you can play around, you can easily corrupt your system.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I used the System Health checker and it was identified as a hot file, which means that it was in use. Then I used Performance Monitor and it said that the file uses some system processes: svchost, System and lsass (the process that handles permissions) and I found its exact location. And trust me, I think that I won't corrupt my computer that easily.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Also, I would always prefer corrupting my system completely than having to use it with increasing lag. I'm so scared about the virus right now that I only start my computer in Safe Mode until I solve the issue.

Comment: Let's start with the basics.  What makes you think the file still exists?  System Information data is replaced/updated/deleted all the time.  Be specific by updating your question.

Comment: Considering that my computer lags more and more every time I use it and having some (but not all) textures broken, I suspect a malware. And do you think that a file that has an odd name like {RJ6NDI3JNSK7}/{OPS5M9GD7K8} (name is for example only) that uses the System, lsass, svchosts and maybe even TrustedInstaller processes is not a virus? But never mind, I think I found the solution. I'll use DOS. @Ramhound

Comment: It’s not a “super protected” folder. It’s simply a hidden system folder. And no offense John, but I can type your question in to google and the second hit after your post is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309531/how-to-gain-access-to-the-system-volume-information-folder

Comment: @Appleoddity According to the tag, I'm asking about Windows 7 here. Not XP. But if you guys don't want to help me, I'll do it myselr.

Comment: The process is almost exactly the same in 7. If you can’t figure it out from the instructions or the numerous articles online you need to strongly consider if you should be screwing with it at all.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with much more security, including permissions. And I can't assign my permissions to the folder because I can't even see it. @Appleoddity

Comment: Oh John. If only you would stop arguing and open your eyes. You can’t see it because you are hiding system folders in your folder view options. It’s exactly what is described in the link I sent. The question is already closed. You’re in over your head here.

Comment: @Appleoddity I didn't know that there was a difference between the "Show hidden files and folders" and "Show hidde system files" options. Oh well, now I checked it and it seems that it's okay, I just randomly encountered its activity when it was writing something. But I also found the real virus in the Window's temp folder. Imagine that it' a .wav file that recreates every time I restart my computer. And it's completely invisible.